# Set file sharing level to 'Anyone with the link' through Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

How to do that? Should I use Google Docs ACL instead and how to configure such ACL?

Answer (score 20):

you have to set following parameters :

```
private Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId) throws Exception{
   Permission newPermission = new Permission();
   newPermission.setType("anyone");
   newPermission.setRole("reader");
   newPermission.setValue("");
   newPermission.setWithLink(true);
   return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
}
```

Comment: Then you can get the sharing link from the field "webContentLink"

Comment: I have written a step by step guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917828/google-drive-sdk-change-item-sharing-permissions/27990794#27990794

Answer (score 4):

Use this method to make your file visible to anyone:

```
private static Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId) throws IOException
{
    Permission newPermission = new Permission();
    newPermission.setType("anyone");
    newPermission.setRole("reader");

    return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
}
```

More details [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

Comment: That makes it publicly available and allows anyone to find it. "Anyone with the link" does not let people find it. Big difference.

Comment: Actually, I just tried this.  When I look at the file with the Drive app on my Android it says "Public on the web (with link) Anyone who has the link".  This appears to be what the user wanted.

Comment: For sake of completeness, if you use "anyone" and "reader" you can use the Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File.WebContentLink (available from the service.Files.Insert operation) as a link to allow anyone to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Documents List API to manage sharing. Please check the docs at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_sharing_permissions_of_resources_via_access_control_lists_acls

Answer (score 0):

For Google Drive API V3, use this method to make your file visible to anyone:

```
    private Permission InsertAnyonePermissionToDownload(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service, String fileId)
    {
        Permission newPermission = new Permission();
        newPermission.Type = "anyone";
        newPermission.Role = "reader";
        return service.Permissions.Create(newPermission, fileId).Execute();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Fabricio H. da Rocha! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand :)