# Insert file to GDrive SDK AND set permissions to anyone with link on the same 'insert' using python

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api, file-permissions

I need to to set the permissions for a GDrive file that i am inserting. Rather than change the permissions after its inserted as a separate call, it makes sense to set the permissions right when its inserted.  I need a link to allow others to download, but not edit.

it inserts fine but does not allow anyone with the link to access... Hmmmm

I have done my google-homework and I have seen the SO quezz and ans at: [Set file sharing level to 'Anyone with the link' through Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155441/set-file-sharing-level-to-anyone-with-the-link-through-google-drive-api)  but still no luck doin it in *one deft call*

I cant believe i need to have a separate `service.permissions().insert` ...so, can anyone see what i'm missing / point me in the right direction?

Here's the relevant snip of my code:

```
def upToGDrive (readPath, title, filename, parent_id = None):
    os.chdir(readPath) #change directory to find right file
    from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
    mime_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    description = 'yeah baby!'
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
    body = {
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'mimeType': mime_type,
        'value': 'none',
        'type': 'anyone',
        'role': 'reader',
        'withLink': 'true'
        }
    # Set the parent folder, if necessary
    if parent_id:
        body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]
    try:
        file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body,media_body=media_body).execute()
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File and permission resources are decoupled, you need to make 2 requests to share a file entity.