# Unable to access sheet created through service account by Google spreadsheet API

Tags: api, url, google-sheets-api, public, service-accounts

Hi I created a spreadsheet using google spreadsheet API with service account credentials (using service token).The problem is that sheet got created in the service account which I cannot access. So how can I make the sheet public? Is there any way to make a sheet public using its URL? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For managing permissions of your drive files (spreadsheet, docs, etc), you'll be using 
[Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) where you'll set the type to "anyone".
You can check thos [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155441/set-file-sharing-level-to-anyone-with-the-link-through-google-drive-api) for code implementation sample.

```
private Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId) throws Exception{
   Permission newPermission = new Permission();
   newPermission.setType("anyone");
   newPermission.setRole("reader");
   newPermission.setValue("");
   newPermission.setWithLink(true);
   return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
}
```